# SQL Duration that value was true

Tags: sql-server

Edited: to include sample data

Looking for guidance on a TSQL query.

I have a table that stores readings from a sensor (Amperage). The table basically has a Date/Time and a Value column.

The date/time increments every 5 seconds (a new record is added on 5 second intervals).

I am trying to build a query to determine the duration of time that the value was >X.

Example Data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f15c0/1/0

The example data is missing chunks to make it smaller but think you would get the idea.

I am trying to get the first record to the next record that goes above 7. This I would do a datediff to get the duration in seconds from when the data started to that first record over 7. I then need to repeat this but now find when it goes below 7.

This way I can see the cycle time duration.

Think of it as your Fridge. The sensor checks in every 5 seconds and sees that the fridge is off and records that. Eventually the fridge turns on and remains on for a period of time. I am trying to get all those cycle times.
I am trying to use Lead and Lag functions...but just getting lost in regards to pulling the data.

Any help?

Comment: It would help if you could provide some sample data in text form (ideally in an actual `create table` statement) rather than a picture so we can use that within our own environments.  You may also want to clarify your question here.  It took me several read throughs to work out why you wanted to show the 1st and 3rd row, though I don't actually think that is what you want, as you seem to be after cycle times.  You also don't mention how you are going to use those cycle times

Comment: *"I am trying to use Lead and Lag functions"* - so show us what you tried.

Comment: @iamdave: you dont have something that automatically sets up a demo environment with a table definitions and imports data from an *image*, like in http://sqlfiddle.com/  **wut?** https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are blocked at my current location, so I can't see your structure. I'll assume you have the following table (I'll ignore PK and other constraints):

```
create table reading(
  entryDate datetime,
  amps int
)
```

Assuming anything above 3 amps is ON, and you want to compute the duty cycles in seconds, then

```
declare @threshold int = 3;
with
state as (
  select entryDate,
         case when amps>@threshold then 'ON' else 'OFF' end state,
         lag( case when amps>@threshold then 'ON' else 'OFF' end )
           over(order by entryDate) prev_state
    from reading
),
transition as (
  select entryDate, state
    from state
   where state <> coalesce(prev_state,'')
)
select entryDate,
       state,
       dateDiff( 
         s,
         entryDate,
         lead(entryDate) over(order by entryDate)
       ) duration
  from transition
 order by 1
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you so much. It does it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @val    numeric(10,5) = 7.0

select  v1.entrydate,
        v1.Amps,
        case when v1.fl = 1 and v1.lg is null then 1
            when v1.lg != v1.fl then 1
            else 0
        end as fl_new
from    (
            select  v1.entrydate,
                    v1.Amps,
                    case when v1.Amps > @val then 1
                        else 0
                    end         as  fl,
                    lag(case when v1.Amps > @val then 1
                        else 0
                    end)    over(order by v1.entrydate) as lg
            from    (
                        select  t.entrydate     as  entrydate,
                                t.Amps          as  Amps
                        from    YourTable t
                    ) v1
        ) v1
where   case when v1.fl = 1 and v1.lg is null then 1
            when v1.lg != v1.fl then 1
            else 0
        end = 1
order by v1.entrydate
```

And don't forget set **YourTable** name and @val (which is "X").

Comment: This did not work. It only returned one row with `DECLARE @val numeric = 7.2.`. However, if you set the numeric precision, e.g. `DECLARE @val NUMERIC(7,4) = 7.2 it does work.  Good code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how fast it'll be, but if you want to try with LAG?

Here's an example that checks for a difference of X>=2

```
SELECT entrydate, amps
FROM
(
    SELECT
     entrydate, amps,
     amps - LAG(amps) OVER (ORDER BY entrydate) AS PrevAmpsDiff
    FROM YourTable
) q
WHERE ABS(FLOOR(PrevAmpsDiff)) >= 2
ORDER BY entrydate;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/ITJ55202)